# One word substitution for 'A woman who shows tantrums to attract men's attention"

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, synonyms

What is the one word substitution for 'A woman who shows tantrums to attract men's attention"? Is it 'Coquette', or is there some better word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Coquette* as a noun is technically a correct word but I've never seen it used.

*A coquettish woman* is an existing but archaic construction, more at home in '30s Film Noir than modern language.

From that word choice I get the idea you are not looking for someone who throws tantrums, tantrums are something small kids have and it involves screaming, crying and pounding your fists on the ground. You could use "drama queen" for someone who behaves like that.

Coquettish is probably the most correct term for a confident, flirtatious woman.

Comment: I once read, aged about 14, in a 1950s sex-education book, that one of the methods used by a wife to provoke sexual desire in her husband  was 'coquetry'. I recall now that the oddness of the word itself struck me as hard as the concept, which seemed a fine one in every way.

Comment: @michaelharvey the etymology is fascinating too, the root is "strutting like a little rooster" (cock-ette), something that for guys is supposed to be base-level self confidence.

Comment: Only those guys who are dickheads.

Comment: Dictionaries sometimes give 'kittenish' as a synonym for 'coquettish', which is how I mainly see the word - as a _very annoying_ and not at all attractive mode of behaviour.